# How to add two columns to make a new one

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  ProductName, ListPrice, Discountpercent from Products
SELECT  (ListPrice/nullif(Discountpercent, 0)) as DiscountAmount FROM Products
SELECT  (ListPrice + DiscountAmount) as DiscountPrice  FROM Products;
```

The DiscountAmount comes up as an invalid column name in the 3rd line. What can i do to make it part of products table

Edit: Also how do do I make Discountpercent calculate as a percent?

Comment: Which database are you actually using?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can either just write out `(ListPrice/nullif(Discountpercent, 0))` wherever you want to use DiscountAmount, or you can use a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx).

This would be the script to do it in SQL Server. If you follow the above link, you will see how to do it from Management Studio.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Products ADD DiscountAmount AS  (ListPrice/nullif(Discountpercent, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (ListPrice + DiscountAmount) as DiscountPrice
FROM (SELECT ProductName, ListPrice, Discountpercent,
             (ListPrice/nullif(Discountpercent, 0)) as DiscountAmount
      FROM Products p
     ) p;
```

Or, alternatively, repeat the expressions in the definition of `DiscountAmount`.